# AWS DynamoDB Item access (get/put/delete) using Global Secondary Indexes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, global, secondary-indexes

Is there a possibility to access (get/put/delete) items of a DynamoDB table using the Global Secondary Indexes (GSI)?
So far, I only see the possiblity of querying over a GSI.

Answer (score 3):

> You can use the Query operation to access one or more items in a
>   global secondary index.

DynamoDB GSI's allows query and scan operations. Other operations such as put, delete and get is not directly possible on top of the index. Rather you can do the action on the original table (e.g delete) which will reflect in the index.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification, Ashan! I am using a conditional delete instead (ConditionExpression). I am just not sure how much latency it causes.